# how to add a white color as a filter on a SKSpriteNode in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, gameplay-kit

I have added a SKSpriteNode in the scene, and I want to add a white color on it to brighten.

```
let armySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "army_img")
armySprite.position = tile.Position
scene.addChild(armySprite)
armySprite.colorBlendFactor = 1
armySprite.color = .white
```

However, there is nothing happened.
So, how can I add a white color filter on armySprite to make it more bright?

The original img is like this:
[image]

Then, what I want is like this :
[image]

Thanks.